# LSTM Accuracy bad on intermediate timesteps with return_sequences=TRUE

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm building a model like this for binary time series classification:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
    layer_lstm(units = 256, input_shape = list(NULL, n_features),
               return_sequences = TRUE, dropout = 0.1, recurrent_dropout = 0.4) %>%
    layer_lstm(units = 256, return_sequences = TRUE, dropout = 0.1, recurrent_dropout = 0.4) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 128) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

Then, during training a create batches of 128 instances that have the same length, i.e. number of lookbacks and for each lookback there is an class in my target vector. For example, the first batch has the dimensions **x = (1:128, 1:8, 1:55)**, **y = (1:128, 1:8, 1)**.

After training, I compute the **Accuracy** and **ROC** on test data. First, I only take the last prediction and label of the sequence. This gives me **ACC = 0.78 and ROC = 0.87**.
So I compute my predictions/labels like this:

```
ret <- lapply(1:max_index, function(i) {
  test_data <- test_gen()
  preds <- predict(model, test_data[[1]], batch_size = dim(test_data[[1]])[[1]])
  preds <- preds[, dim(preds)[[2]], 1] # take last predictions
  labels <- test_data[[2]]
  labels <- labels[, dim(labels)[[2]]] # take last label
  return(list(preds = preds, labels = labels))
})
```

However, when I compute the metrics over the predictions and labels for each timestep in a sequence it seems like the model has nothing learned, as the **ACC and ROC is about 0.5**.

```
ret <- lapply(1:max_index, function(i) {
  test_data <- test_gen()
  preds <- predict(model, test_data[[1]], batch_size = dim(test_data[[1]])[[1]])
  preds <- as.vector(t(as.matrix(preds))) # take all predictions
  labels <- test_data[[2]]
  labels <- as.vector(t(as.matrix(labels))) # take all labels
  return(list(preds = preds, labels = labels))
})
```

Is my understanding of `return_sequences=TRUE` false?